# Javascript delimiter new line

Tags: javascript

I need to split a word based on a user entered delimiter and then display them in a div with each word on a separate line. I don't know how to display each of the separated word on a different line. Here is the code:

```
function customBreakIt(){
var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value; //grabs text to break
var location = document.getElementById("textbox2").value; //grabs user entered delimiter
var list = text.split(location);    //splits the text at the delimiter   
var recombined = ""; 
var newLine = document.createElement("br");
for(x in list){         
    recombined = recombined + list[x];        
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = recombined; //changes the <p> text in an ID called 'second' to recombined
    //now I need to also let each new word appear on a separate line
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your *recombined list* into div and concatenate the output:

```
//var newLine = document.createElement("br");
for (x in list) {         
    recombined += '<div>' + list[x] + '</div>';
}
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = recombined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `document.createElement("p")` for each word, add the text to the new `<p>` element, and append the new element to the second container.